# Laravel y Datatables como mostrar un campo extra que no viene en la tabla que mando llamar

Tags: ajax, laravel-5, datatables

quisiera saber como puedo mostrar datos de dos tablas en una sola datatable?

En la parte de "usuario" seria el nombre del usuario pero este pertenece a otra tabla
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es lo que tengo en mi controlador

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Datatables;
use App\Usuario;
use DB;
use App\Resultado;

class DataTablesController extends Controller
{
    /**
 * Displays datatables front end view
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\View\View
 */
public function datatable()
    {
        return view('usuarios.resultado');
    }

    public function getPosts()
    {
        $model = Usuario::query();
        // return datatables()->eloquent(Usuario::query())->toJson();
        return Datatables::eloquent($model)
        ->addColumn('action', function($user) {
            return '
                    <br><a href="' . route('VerResultado', $user->id_usu) . '" class="btn btn-xs btn-success" title="Detalles">Ver Detalles</a>
                ';
        })
        ->toJson();

    }

    public function getRes()
    {
        $resultado = Resultado::query();

        return Datatables::eloquent($resultado)
        ->toJson();
    }
}
```

Y esto es básicamente la función ajax.

```
  $('#resultado').DataTable({
      dom: 'Bfrtip',
      "procesing": true,
      "serverside": true,
       responsive: true,
       buttons: [
      'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print' 
      ],
      "ajax": '{{ route('datatable/getres') }}',
      "columns":[ 
        {data: 'id', name: 'id'}, 
        {data: 'sintetico', name: 'sintetico'},
        {data: 'idealista', name: 'idealista'},
        {data: 'pragmatico', name: 'pragmatico'},
        {data: 'analitico', name: 'analitico'},
        {data: 'realista', name: 'realista'},
        {data: 'total', name: 'total'},
        {data: 'id_usu', name: 'id_usu'},
      ],
      order: [[0, 'asc']]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

lo que tiene que hace es utilizar la función belongsto en laravel, en la consulta se deber añadir la siguiente line

```
Resultado::with('usuario_pk')->get();
```

en el modelo de Resultado deber definir una funcion llamada usuario_pk, 
y donde App\users corresponde la tabla de  datos foraneo
y la funcion hasMany me permiter traer de 1 a muchos datos

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Resultado extends Model {

    protected $table    = 'resultado';
    protected $fillable = [];

    public function usuario_pk() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\users', 'id_usu');
    }
    public function especie_id_all() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ArbolesModel', 'barrio_id');
    } 
}
```

y en la vista traer los datos usuario_pk->name

```
 {data: 'usuario_pk->name', name: 'usuario_pk->name'},
```

Comment: si utlilizo un controlador para mandar los datos al datatable, no importa esto?